# How to get the immature balance of an account?

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc, immature-coins

I have run bitcoind and have several accounts. How do I get the immature balance of one account using RPC calls (if possible) ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the `listtransactions` command, you can see your immature coinbase transactions listed with category `immature`.

`listtransactions` appears to include both spent and unspent transactions in general, but since immature coins cannot be spent, that shouldn't be a problem.

Since accounts are now deprecated, you can get the immature balance for the entire wallet with `getwalletinfo`; look at the `immature` field.

Note that `getbalance` does not include immature coins.

Answer (score 0):

With the getbalance command you can specify an account and minimum confirms, I'm assuming my immature balance you mean account balance containing unconfirmed transactions. By default it's at one.

```
getbalance [account] [minconf=1]
```

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_calls_list

Comment: Usually "immature" means generated coins under 100 blocks deep in the blockchain. (I don't know if there's a way to get this in balance form from bitcoind)

Comment: Yes as @Luke-Jr says, I meant immature in that way, not transactions with low confirmations.

Comment: Can someone point me to the code section in source tree, I am running some experiments and I would like to change the 100 block limit to 10 blocks for the same. Thanks