# Local Testnet3, where do the new coins get sent to?

Tags: blockchain, json-rpc, testnet

I'm trying to setup a local testnet with multiple nodes. Currently I have three nodes, and their mining powers are almost the same.

When I use `listaccounts` RPC call, all the wallets have 0 coins. Even when I call `listunspent 0`, there are no transactions listed. How do I check how many coins I have mined so far? There have been 50 blocks in the blockchain so far.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newly mined coins are [immature](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/20120/what-was-the-goal-of-creating-the-feature-of-immature-coins) and cannot be spent until 100 more blocks are mined.

`bitcoind` does not show immature coins as part of your balance, but you can see them using the `listtransactions` command, as I explain [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/30633/5757).